# WP_query category__in array only pulls from first category id

Tags: categories, wordpress

I am trying to get ALL post id's for posts in these categories (relation OR): 10,11,12,13,14 with certain extra attributes. My problem is with the categories however.

My args array for my wp_query is as follows:

```
$args = array(
                        'orderby' =>'ID',
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'category__in' => array('10','11','12','13','14'),
                        'meta_query' => array( 
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                     'key' => 'joke_type',                 
                                     'value' => $type,                 
                                     'type' => 'CHAR',                 
                                     'compare' =>  '='
                                 ),
                                     array(
                                         'key' => 'joke_rating',
                                         'value' => 3,
                                         'type' => 'SIGNED',
                                         'compare' => '>='
                                     )
                         ),
                         'fields' => 'ids' 
                );
```

This only gets me posts from category 10 (or whichever ID I place first in the array). I also tried: `'category__in' => '10,11,12,13,14'` and `'category' => '10,11,12,13,14'` and `'cat' => '10,11,12,13,14'` All act the same.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 6):

Category IDs inside your `category__in` array should be integers rather than strings.

Change:

```
'category__in' => array('10','11','12','13','14'),
```

To:

```
'category__in' => array( 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ),
```